# Snow in Halacha

Tags: halacha, weather

Name the many references in different contexts in Halacha to snow?

Comment: Too broad? [15]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Whether a frozen mass of it can constitute the wall part of an *eruv* demarcation. ([Aruch Hashulchan או"ח שסב:טו](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%A1%D7%91#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A9.D7.A1.D7.91_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.98.D7.95))
- Purges sins. (See the *Gr"a* on "לא תירא לביתה משלג".)

Comment: Wow thats a really good one thanx

Comment: I heard something similar from Rav Shelomo Levenstein Shelit"a.

Answer (score 5):

- A description of the color-shade of *tzara'as*.
- Whether it counts as water vis-a-vis a *mikva*.

Answer (score 4):

Can it be used to cover blood after Shechitah
Can you toivel or your Keilim in a snow drift

[An Article on the topic.](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2009/01/more-on-snowsnow-halacha.html)

Comment: #13 on O.C. 320:9 has me intrigued. Thanks for linking!

Answer (score 4):

That you're not allowed to break it up on Shabbos in order to use the melted water (Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 320:9).

Answer (score 4):

Similar: whether you can wash your hands in it (for eating bread, waking up, etc...)

Answer (score 4):

- Does snow invalidate the shach of the sukkah?  The Aruch Hashulchan says probably: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%98

And from the same section of the Aruch Hashulchan:

- Is snow considered to be a roof for the laws of tum'ah?
- Snow is not m'kabel tum'ah.

Answer (score 3):

- Whether snow is muktzah.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite Halacha, but the string changing color to white as snow on Yom Kippur to show that atonement for the Klal was successful .

btw: this week yutorah.org has featured this week 
http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/740735/Rabbi_Mordechai_Torczyner/Snowball_Fights_in_Jewish_Law_and_Thought

Answer (score 2):

An important Shiur on all things Having to do with snow a VIdeo Here Chopping on shabbos,salting,Shoveling and snowball fights Here:

http://www.torahanytime.com/scripts/media.php?file=media/Rabbi/Shlomo_Pearl/2010-01-10/Halachot_of_Snow_on_Shabbat/Rabbi__Shlomo_Pearl__Halachot_of_Snow_on_Shabbat__2010-01-10.wmv

Answer (score 1):

- Ben Ish Hai S"B Yito 11 permits people to walk on snow on Shabbat. [Also, later on he discusses if you allowed to mush snow into a cup of water to make it cold, and prohibits it (as well as S"A O"H 320- and Alex's answer). ]
- Shulhan Aruch (ibid.) prohibits the crushing of ice, however, permits the placing of it in a cup to make things cold (also see for lengthy discussion the aforementioned BI"H and later on in that Parasha).

See also the Mefarshim on that S"A.